# How to tag video player for opening video files from other apps?

Tags: android

I wrote a vidoeplayer and was wondering... when you click a video file from some other app, say a file browser, a list of apps appear, that can open this video file.

How do I make my player also appear on that list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register the `Intent` you want in your activity.

From API 15, you need to add [CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC) to your app manifest, possibly under [ACTION_MAIN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN) intent filter.

If you want to target down to API 8, also use [INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER) in the intent filter.
Here's a sample manifest part..

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <!--  If this is the main activity -->
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" /> <!-- To make sure we let Android know that we accept video -->
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Hope this helps.