# How to tag audio player for opening audio files from other apps?

Tags: android

I am working on music player application. When you click a audio file from file browser, a list of apps appear, that can open this audio file.

How do I make my player also appear on that list? Below is the code which i have added in manifest for launching my activity.

```
<activity
 android:name="com.view.HomeActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

I tried with the following code as well taken from :
[How to tag video player for opening video files from other apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897511/how-to-tag-video-player-for-opening-video-files-from-other-apps)

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC" /> 
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 <data android:mimeType="video/*" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use:

```
<data android:mimeType="video/*" />
```

you should use:

```
android:mimeType="audio/*" />
```

try this section:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:pathPattern=".*mp3" android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Sorry,that was a mistake,i had tried it with audio itself. Now, I added  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> and  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> and its working. Thanks for ur help!

Comment: adding data scheme is not working. Btw, what is the purpose of adding scheme here?

Comment: This code worked for me: <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <data
                    android:mimeType="audio/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*mp3" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: I have got another issue, looking forward for ur reply. Once i select my app and play songs, my app opens up the next time when ever i select file explorer. Can u pls help me out to resolve this?