# Phone not showing my video player name to play videos

Tags: android

I had develope an android video player and putted a video in the res/drawable folder as a default video.

Then after installation of the .apk in mobile when i clicked on any video then my phone showed the list of already installed media players to play the video, but my player is not there in the list.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="center" >
 <VideoView android:id="@+id/video_view" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center"/>
 </FrameLayout>
```

**Code**

```
 @Override protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // set the main layout of the activity 
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //set the media controller buttons 
    if(mediaControls == null)
     { mediaControls = new MediaController(AndroidVideoViewExample.this);
     } //initialize the VideoView 
     myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view); 
    }
```

what should i do?

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Comment: I just used Videoview in athe activity.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="center" >
<VideoView
 android:id="@+id/video_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"/>
  </FrameLayout>

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // set the main layout of the activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //set the media controller buttons

        if (mediaControls == null) {
            mediaControls = new MediaController(AndroidVideoViewExample.this);
        }
        //initialize the VideoView
        myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
}

Comment: Where is the Click Listener?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it so that others will benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want the Android to know that your App can play videos and add it to the list of suggested Apps when the user clicks on any video, you need to add an intent in your Android Manifest. This sample code will let the OS know that your app can be used as a Media Player that can accept video files. Also, the MyActivity will be launched when the user chooses to play the video with your app.

    <activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <!--  If this is the main activity -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" /> <!-- To make sure we let Android know that we accept video -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Reference: [How to tag video player for opening video files from other apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897511/how-to-tag-video-player-for-opening-video-files-from-other-apps)

Comment: Hey I had done it but after doing this when I install apk in mobile its shortcut is not coming in my phone, but it is available in installed application.

Also phone not showing my apk name in suggestion player list.